# First samplecode of OpenGL redbook crashes in first init line

Tags: c, opengl

I was able to compile the first sample code of the redbook's 8th edition but when I try to run the programm it crashes in the first fucntion call of init with reading from 0x000... error.

```
enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };
GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];
const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

void init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    /*
...
*/
}
```

The preciding declarations is all `NumVAOs` is not found:

> NumVAOs    CXX0017: Error: symbol "NumVAOs" not found

I also have no clue where this gets initialized.
So how it can be that NumVAOs is unkown and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm confused --- is the problem that your compiler can't find `NumVAOs`, or that it crashes while running? Because it can't do both (since you can't even *start* it if it doesn't compile).

Comment: @user694733 D'oh, you're right of course. Brain malfunction. Comment deleted.

Comment: I'm not getting the comments. Sorry. It compiles all is fine not even a warning. But when i start the programm it crashes (didn't change anything from the sample in teh book) so i started debugging. and figgured out it crashes in the line where the posted function invokes. so I checked the arguments parsed in and saw: NumVAOs isn't even known. So I don't know how to affect or prevent that crash. And since It is the first code from that book, I can't really do error detection by my self, as I don't know what all this is doing.

Comment: @ryyker what do you mean by "visible"? It compiles. So yeah, I added the lib paths, or Am I getting you wrong?

Comment: @ryyker setting `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; ` made it run without error. But I don't get teh explanation of that post. Does it mean I'm using an outdated glew version? Or what is the reason? Or do I have to use later when my programm is going in production anyway to use that experimental stuff?